# MySQL Workbench - Stored Procedure - Error - No reference in manual

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL workbench 8.0.18 on a mac.

I am trying to run the following stored procedure using $$ as my delimiter. It is not running and giving me the error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 3

And here is the code with the delimiter:

```
delimiter $$

create procedure HelloWorld()
begin
 select 'Hello World!';
end $$
```

I have gone through the documentation for mysql workbench but could not find any relevant answer pertaining to it. 
Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run this in a NORMAL query tab when you want to use DELIMITER:

If you want to add a procdure in **new_procedure Routine**

Leave out the DELIMITER completely,

When you save the procedure Workbench will add the DELIMITER abd DEFINER automatically

[image: Fuction create stored procedure]

Comment: Hi nbk. Thank you for replying to my question. But I am running it in a normal query tab within a database. But still it is giving me the same error!

Comment: Copy the text from your post and try it again and add a DELIMITER ; Besides it is godd practice to write MYSQL commands in BIG LETTERS, that makes it better readable.

Comment: Hi nbk. I tried it again. And this time I used a delimiter and also typed the statements in Upper Case. It is still not working. Cannot figure out what is wrong!

Comment: start everything new als the mysql server, i had hoped, that  you had entered a character that mysql doesn't like.  hence you should copy the text from your post and try this, so give it a try

Comment: Hi nbk. Still not working. Anyway thank you for all your suggestions and recommendations. Will try to figure out later as to what is the problem.

Comment: No problem, use the **create stored procedure** functio of workbench and see it that works out better. If that is also not working,i would recomend to delete and reinstall it.

Comment: Hi nbk. I looked for create stored procedure function in my version of the workbench but could not find it. I also deleted and reinstalled workbench but it is just the same. I am unable to create a stored procedure even as the root user. I am guessing it has got to do something with the serve settings. I will research about it and try to solve it otherwise whenever in your spare time please try to see if you can get any answers for it. Thank you!

Comment: I added a picture, where you can see the functiom when you right click on stored procedures. Even when all fails use some other program https://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-workbench/?platform=mac

Comment: Hi nbk. Thank you for the resource. I figured out a way to circumvent the problem. I am able to connect to mysql server via terminal and creating my stored procedures there with the same syntax. And this time it is not throwing me any error. And after I do that, the same is getting reflected in my workbench :)

Comment: Super but with complicaed procedures where you must debug the procedure, a ide is very handy.